# Vscode extensions not working with multiple instances

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am creating VsCode Extension using typescript and I have tried to take all the activities using events. For instance, Whenever a file is opened I have listeners to these events so event is fired and I will write the name of file to the console but it is not working when I open another instances of vscode using `File-> New Window`  option.
   Can any one tell me why this is happening?

Comment: Do you have the extension installed, or are you running the Extension Development Host?

Comment: Hi No I didn't install the extension just I have created the extension and tested it pressing F5 key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you open a new window from the Extension Development Host instance, the behavior is the same as if you were doing the same action from a normal instance.  You will notice that the new window does not state *[Extension Development Host]*.  It has no knowledge of your extension since it isn't an installed extension.

About the only thing you can do is copy your extension into the extensions folder (i.e. temporarily "install" it) and give it a try.

Comment: it works when i copied the project to %USERPROFILE%\.vscode\extensions