# Unable to open up 2 instances of vscode extension host

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

### Goal:

Open up 2 instances of vscode extension host so that I can debug the networking of my visual studio code extension

### Problem (attempted solutions):

1. I've found https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/99936 , which suggests duplicating the launch config and giving it a different name, then running them. I changed my `launch.json` to this

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Run Extension",
            "type": "extensionHost",
            "request": "launch",
            "args": [
                "--extensionDevelopmentPath=${workspaceFolder}"
            ],
            "outFiles": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/out/**/*.js"
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "${defaultBuildTask}"
        },
        {
            "name": "Run Extension 2",
            "type": "extensionHost",
            "request": "launch",
            "args": [
                "--extensionDevelopmentPath=${workspaceFolder}"
            ],
            "outFiles": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/out/**/*.js"
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "${defaultBuildTask}"
        },
        {
            "name": "Extension Tests",
            "type": "extensionHost",
            "request": "launch",
            "args": [
                "--extensionDevelopmentPath=${workspaceFolder}",
                "--extensionTestsPath=${workspaceFolder}/out/test/suite/index"
            ],
            "outFiles": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/out/test/**/*.js"
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "${defaultBuildTask}"
        }
    ]
}
```

Then, I clicked on "Run Extension" and "Run Extension 2" in the top left corner of the "Run and Debug" menu. (with the green triangle).
"Run Extension" successfully triggered 1 instance of the extension host, but "Run Extension 2" caused the extension host from "Run Extension" to refresh and become the extension host for "Run Extension 2", leaving me with only 1 active extension host, instead of creating 1 more.

2. I tried clicking the "Run Extension" button twice, which should work according to https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/110226 . However, when I click the button the second time, it comes up with a prompt asking " 'Run Extension' is already running. Do you want to start another instance? ". When I click "yes", I encounter the same problem from the 1st attempted solution, where the 2nd extension host simply replaces the 1st extension host.

This isn't expected behavior (at least according to the discussion in the Github issue), so I'm a bit confused.

### Working (but inefficient) solution

I have found [Vscode extensions not working with multiple instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38303086/vscode-extensions-not-working-with-multiple-instances) which tells me to copy the extension into the extensions folder, but that is a bit slow and inconvenient, which is why I'm asking here for a better solution.

I am currently using the basic "Hello World" example from https://code.visualstudio.com/api/get-started/your-first-extension as the extension

Comment: have you tried to create a `New Window` open the same workspace and launch it also from there

Comment: I can't get the new window to open up the same workspace. It simply makes the already open window with the workspace go in front of the new window (into focus), and the new window doesn't open the workspace.

Comment: what if you run a second version in a virtual machine

Comment: I would consider that somewhat inefficient because of the virtual machine set up.